# ¿Como hacer que dos elementos HTML del mismo tipo en mi codigo puedan tener estilos diferentes?

Tags: html, css

Logro poner el color lo malo es cuando vuelvo y pongo el código para hacer otra lista comienza a repetirse

**Ejemplo:** https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select

```
/*the container must be positioned relative:*/
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.custom-select select {
  display: none; /*hide original SELECT element:*/
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

/*style the arrow inside the select element:*/
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}

/*point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):*/
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}

/*style the items (options), including the selected item:*/
.select-items div,.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

/*style items (options):*/
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

/*hide the items when the select box is closed:*/
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

<h2>Custom Select</h2>

<!--surround the select box with a "custom-select" DIV element. Remember to set the width:-->
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select>
    <option value="0">Select car:</option>
    <option value="1">Audi</option>
    <option value="2">BMW</option>
    <option value="3">Citroen</option>
    <option value="4">Ford</option>
    <option value="5">Honda</option>
    <option value="6">Jaguar</option>
    <option value="7">Land Rover</option>
    <option value="8">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="9">Mini</option>
    <option value="10">Nissan</option>
    <option value="11">Toyota</option>
    <option value="12">Volvo</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script>
var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
    /*for each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box, and the selected item:*/
        var y, i, k, s, h;
        s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
        for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
          if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
            s.selectedIndex = i;
            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
            for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
              y[k].removeAttribute("class");
            }
            this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
            break;
          }
        }
        h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes, and open/close the current select box:*/
      e.stopPropagation();
      closeAllSelect(this);
      this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
      this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
    });
}
function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document, except the current select box:*/
  var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
/*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box, then close all select boxes:*/
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
</script>
```

Comment: Muestra el código que llevas hecho hasta el momento para poder ayudarte.

Comment: no se quieren mandar

Comment: @umaru218 El html y el css que tienes

Comment: estoy tratando de mandarlo y no quiere

Comment: @ElliotWilliamson

Comment: @umaru218, por favor pega tu código en texto, no en imágenes, será mucho más fácil de analizar y tratar de ayudar.

Comment: Lo hice pero no se mandan

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select aqui se encuentran si se repiten las etiquetas me aparece asi

Comment: Saludos, sin el código necesario para tener un ejemplo mínimo y verificable no podemos ofrecerte una respuesta y dado eso también generaría el cierre de tu pregunta

Comment: He añadido tu código, pero en el ejemplo del enlace que nos traes, no veo lo que dices de que el select se repite, ¿puedes aclarar mejor el problema que tienes?

Comment: @ track3r ese es un ejemplo mis còdigos no me deja subirlos

Comment: hay estan pero cuando lo vuelves a repetir para colocar otra etiqueta se repiten

Comment: Si no entiendo mal, lo que tienes que hacer es identificar a cada select por su id (identificador) o clase única, si no tienen solo tienes que añadirla. Otra opción es usar los selectores nth de css para indicar qué elemento quieres modificar. En caso de tener id, el selector comenzará con # y si se trata de una clase, con .

Comment: gracias por la ayuda

Comment: cuál seria el id?

Comment: El que tu pongas a cada select en el atributo del html, por ejemplo <select id="marca">, entonces para definir un color a ése select sería #marca { color: green; } si luego tienes otro select con id="tipo", sería #tipo

Comment: no me funciona @track3r

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pega la parte que has modificado para ver que has hecho, de lo contrario no puedo hacer nada.

Comment: <select id="marca"> #marca { color: green; } me dijiste que lo pongas asi cuando lo pongo no aparece el color y para que me salga tuve que cambiar el select por option

Comment: La parte de <select id="marca"> es html y reemplaza a tu parte de código en dónde dice <select>, es decir, le añades un identificador. La parte de #marca { color: green; } es css y va entre los tags <style> y </style> de tu código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu css podés utilizar la clase **select** para establecer el color del texto de tu select:

```
select
{
  color:red;
}
```

Si queres que todas las opciones del select se diferencien utiliza la clase **select option**:

```
select option
{
    color:black; 
}
```

Para establecer un color especifico por cada opt podes hacerlo indicando el valor con  **select option [value]**:

```
select option[value="1"] 
{
  background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
}
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar mas clases css para lograrlo como a continuación:

```css
.tipo {
  background: red;
}

.subtipo1 {
  background: blue;
}

.subtipo2 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="tipo">TIPO 1</div>
<div class="tipo subtipo1">TIPO 1 subtipo 1</div>
<div class="tipo subtipo2">TIPO 1 subtipo 2</div>
<div class="tipo subtipo1 subtipo2">TIPO 1 subtipo 2</div>
```

**OJO**

el estilo final que quede en tu elemento depende del orden que tienen tus clases css (el orden dentro del archivo css o dentro de la etiqueta style)